# Function doing different things when being called the same way

Tags: android, function

Hello I'm having an issue where it seems that a line of code is completely ignored  or is giving different result every time.

```
private void getCard() {
    switch (temp4) {

        case 1:
            System.out.println("ACE");
            ValueToBeStored = 11;
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("TEN");
            ValueToBeStored = 10;
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("TWO");
            ValueToBeStored = 2;
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("THREE");
            ValueToBeStored = 3;
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("FOUR");
            ValueToBeStored = 4;
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("FIVE");
            ValueToBeStored = 5;
            break;
        case 7:
            System.out.println("SIX");
            ValueToBeStored = 6;
            break;
        case 8:
            System.out.println("SEVEN");
            ValueToBeStored = 7;
            break;
        case 9:
            System.out.println("EIGHT");
            ValueToBeStored = 8;
            break;
        case 10:
            System.out.println("NINE");
            ValueToBeStored = 9;
            break;
        case 12:
            System.out.println("JACK");
            ValueToBeStored = 10;
            break;
        case 11:
            System.out.println("QUEEN");
            ValueToBeStored = 10;
            break;
        case 13:
            System.out.println("KING");
            ValueToBeStored = 10;
            break;


    }

    {
        switch (CardToBeStored) {

            case 1:
                p1card1 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 2:
                p1card2 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 3:
                p1card3 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 4:
                p1card4 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 5:
                p1card5 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 6:
                p2card1 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 7:
                p2card2 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 8:
                p2card3 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 9:
                p2card4 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 10:
                p2card5 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 11:
                p3card1 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 12:
                p3card2 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 13:
                p3card3 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 14:
                p3card4 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 15:
                p3card5 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 16:
                p4card1 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 17:
                p4card2 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 18:
                p4card3 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 19:
                p4card4 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 20:
                p4card5 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 21:
                p5card1 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 22:
                p5card2 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 23:
                p5card3 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 24:
                p5card4 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
            case 25:
                p5card5 = ValueToBeStored;
                break;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("CARD" + CardToBeStored + " STORED AS " + ValueToBeStored);


}
```

temp4 is set before getCard() is called and so is CardToBeStored. My main issue is that when temp4 is 11, QUEEN is printed in logcat but ValueToBeStored doesn't change to 10, but instead keeps its previous value. 
For ex) 
getCard() temp->4 ValueToBeStored = 4
getCard() temp->11 ValueToBeStored = 4 
All of the other cases work. Any idea what would be causing this? If need be I can send my entire class file.

Comment: To clarify, ONLY the Queen case doesn't switch ValueToBeStored to 10? Jack/King do?

Comment: >If need be I can send my entire class file
Yes, please.

Comment: Yes, only the queen does it @Phiat

Comment: I don't want to post my entire class file here, I'd rather PM it you @khalafnt

Comment: That's quite odd. I'll also need the class file if I'm to help further. @Seabass77

Comment: Stack Overflow is about share knowledge, even if it implies sharing your top secret code. Is not a personal service.

Comment: I don't feel comfortable unless it's public. I guess I have nothing to do then. Sorry.

Comment: Surely you could share card-game code... Make this page scroll!

Comment: @Phiat http://pastebin.com/C5Wb1DNM That's all of the class file

Comment: I'd like to help you, but the code is too difficult to follow. You can minimize a lot of it with a few objects.

Comment: Are you sure you're working in the same, single thread? Have you tried to change order of 11 and 12 (queen and jack) ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I've removed the stuff that isn't relevant and added comments maybe this is easier to follow  http://pastebin.com/PtzE3QZw I do think that the real issue is in the code that I posted above but again, willing to try anything

Comment: @AterLux I did trying switching the order, that's why case 12 is before case 11. What's odd is that it doesn't matter what number i put it on it works the same.

Comment: Strange issue. Try to use Log.d instead of System.out.println

Comment: @AterLux I tried using Log.d and noticed that it is printing in the log but it happens a mere 2 seconds after System.out.println("CARD" + CardToBeStored + " STORED AS " + ValueToBeStored);(At the end)

Comment: You should paste the entire class file from your **first** pastebin link into this question in case the pastebin links ever go stale. The question doesn't have enough context to look like anything other than a weird problem without the full code so won't be useful to people in future. It's only in the **first** pastebin link you can see the multiple `Handler`s triggering each other at timed intervals and the many functions manipulating member variables that makes you think it all smells a bit wrong, so I'd guess your problem is somewhere in that area. Your code is _very_ difficult to follow.

Comment: @HexAndBugs How would I make my code (in general) easier to follow?

Comment: It's tough to say,  as I really don't understand what you're trying to do. I'd start by not using so many member variables and instead passing values as arguments to functions and then returning values. It's generally considered good practise to make the scope of the variables as small as possible, rather than having member variables that are visible to the whole class. Using meaningful variable names (`temp4` means nothing to me). Adding comments to your code and making sure they are correct.

Comment: I'd also look at applying fairly standard Java coding conventions like starting variables & function names with a lower case letter and camel casing the words - e.g. `dealOtherCards3` instead of `dealothercards3`. Although it doesn't affect the functionality, I find it quite distracting reading variable and function names that start with an upper case letter and deciphering non-camel cased names. Doing this stuff would be a good start and increase the chances people can help you more. There's probably lots more people could suggest once they understand your code better too.